# mySQL - Showing data with LEFT JOIN table but without showing the result of the connected data

Tags: mysql, database

I have 2 tables for `mySQL` database that is `applicants` and `applicant_childrens`. The `applicants` table contains details of user for both parents and their children. The `applicant_childrens` is the join table for the connection of the parents and children. Below are the details of the tables.

**applicants**

```
id | name  | ic   | address
----------------------------
1  | Amran | 5115 | KL
2  | Zack  | 1234 | KL
3  | Nur   | 1156 | Sel
4  | Aisya | 8701 | Sabah
```

**applicant_childrens**

```
id | ic_parent | ic_chidlren 
----------------------------
1  | 5115      |  1156
2  | 5115      |  8701
```

My question is, how do I want to select a data that show all the applicants details with the joining table but without showing the name of the children? For example, the table that I want is:

```
id | name  | ic   | address | id | ic_parent | ic_children
----------------------------------------------------------
1  | Amran | 5115 | KL      | 1  | 5115      | 1156
1  | Amran | 5115 | KL      | 2  | 5115      | 8701
2  | Zack  | 1234 | KL
```

At the moment the result that I get is as below:

```
SELECT * FROM `applicants` ap 
LEFT JOIN applicant_childrens ac 
ON ap.ic=ac.ic_parent

id | name  | ic   | address | id | ic_parent | ic_children
----------------------------------------------------------
1  | Amran | 5115 | KL      | 1  | 5115      | 1156
1  | Amran | 5115 | KL      | 2  | 5115      | 8701
2  | Zack  | 1234 | KL
3  | Nur   | 1156 | Sel
4  | Aisya | 8701 | Sabah
```

Comment: Since you're joining to applicant_childrens using ic_parent, isn't `name `the name of the parent and not the child?  Aren't you already NOT showing the name of the child?

Answer (score 1):

You can try below query -

```
SELECT * FROM applicants ap 
LEFT JOIN applicant_childrens ac
ON ap.ic=ac.ic_parent
WHERE ap.ic NOT IN (SELECT ic_children FROM applicant_childrens)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried your query but it still give result of id no. 3 and 4

Comment: I tried to edit your query with `SELECT * FROM applicants ap LEFT JOIN applicant_childrens ac ON ap.ic=ac.ic_parent WHERE ap.ic NOT IN (SELECT ic_children FROM applicant_childrens) ` and got the correct result :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to clarify your expected results: Why are you expecting Zack (`ic=1234`) to show up, but not Nur or Aisya? None of those 3 users are anywhere in your `applicant_childrens` table. From the way I understand your logic, it would seem that only Amran's name should show up.

I think you need to start by selecting from `applicant_children`, and then `LEFT JOIN`ing to `applicants` twice: Once for the parent, and once for the parent.

Doing something like this:

```
SELECT
    parent.`id` AS applicant_id,
    parent.`name`,
    parent.`ic`,
    parent.`address`,
    ac.`id` AS ac_id,
    parent.`ic` AS ic_parent,
    child.`ic` AS ic_children
FROM applicant_childrens ac
    LEFT JOIN applicants parent ON
        parent.ic = ac.ic_parent
    LEFT JOIN applicants child ON
        child.ic = ac.ic_children
```

yields results like this:

```
applicant_id name   ic      address ac_id ic_parent   ic_children
1            Amran  5115    KL      1     5115        1156
1            Amran  5115    KL      2     5115        8701
```

Note that Record 2 from your `applicants` table doesn't appear. Again, you need to clarify why you would expect it to.